# CocoaPods how to add strings bundle?

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

What should the `resource_bundles` line look like in the .podspec if I just want to include my strings files named "MyAwesomeLib.strings" from all the .lproj folders?

I've tried the following:

```
s.resource_bundle = { 'MyAwesomeLibResources' => ['MyAwesomeLib/*.lproj/MyAwesomeLib.strings'] }
```

But it hasn't worked. It builds the .bundle file fine, but inside it aren't all the pruned .lproj folders, but just a single MyAwesomeLib.strings file outside of any folder.

Any idea how to include the MyAwesomeLib.strings files from all the .lproj folders, but without including all the other junk inside the .lproj folders?

Answer (score 1):

Simple use "directory/*" will keep the fielder structure under. e.g.

```
s.ios.resource_bundle = { 'grabKitBundle' => 'Resources/*'}
```

All directories structure under "Resources" will be copied as there are, and will build in bundle correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Other libraries which have similar features just outright [include the bundle](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/iRate/1.8/iRate.podspec) in the resources and that brings in all the strings files. Would this model work for you?